# logging in node.js using debug library

Tags: node.js, debugging, winston

I'm currently using [debug library](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug).

Is there a way I can save the output texts from debug library to a file for log like Winston.

For example... pseudo code...

```
var debug = require('debug')('test');
// debug.bind('test.log'); // <-- something like this..
debug('hello world');
```

So.. 'hello world' should be in a test.log

Comment: They suggest to redirect the output like `$ node app.js 2> output.txt` https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/85 or `$ DEBUG_FD=3 node script.js 3>debug.log` https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/146

Answer (score 3):

I found this site where the author uses Winston.

```
var winston = require('winston');
//log your output to a file also
winston.add(winston.transports.File, { filename: 'somefile.log' });
//log some outputs
winston.log('info', 'Hello distributed log files!');
winston.error('Who let the dogs out?!');
```

Source: http://devgigs.blogspot.kr/2014/01/mastering-nodejs-logging.html?m=1

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. but as I updated the question.. I want to log something using debug library not winston... is it possible?

Comment: Ahh, sorry I misunderstood your question.